# What is the minimum/maximum input size for deflate() or inflate() in zlib?

Tags: c, buffer, zlib, deflate, inflate

When using `zlib`, what is the minimum and maximum input buffer size that can handle `deflate()` and `inflate()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum buffer size is 0. Regarding the maximum size, see the [zlib FAQ](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html):

> *Can zlib work with greater than 4 GB of data?*
>
> Yes. `inflate()` and `deflate()` will process any amount of data correctly. Each call of `inflate()` or `deflate()` is limited to input and output chunks of the maximum value that can be stored in the compiler's "unsigned int" type, but there is no limit to the number of chunks. Note however that the `strm.total_in` and `strm_total_out` counters may be limited to 4 GB. These counters are provided as a convenience and are not used internally by `inflate()` or `deflate()`. The application can easily set up its own counters updated after each call of `inflate()` or `deflate()` to count beyond 4 GB.